# how to meter natural gas usage in a part of the home

Tags: furnace, natural-gas, meter

I rent my basement out. It's currently heated via electricity. It's cold where I live, and my renter's electric bills are high.

I'm thinking of installing a natural [gas wall furnace](https://www.google.com/search?q=gas%20wall%20furnace) in the basement. These things go in a single central location on a level (i.e. a floor), and bleed heat to the rest of the level (i.e. floor). No "blown air" being piped to vents in each room. They're quite common in my area. I think there's just one vent-to-outdoors needed for the burn-off from the gas.

The basement has a gas cooking stove (I pay for that gas), so there's already a natural gas pipe feeding the basement.

The issue is potential abuse. Currently, the renter has their own separate electric meter, and so they are responsible for how much heat they consume. But if I installed this gas wall furnace, the gas would be under a single bill paid by me (because there's a single natural gas meter to the house, and it may be too expensive/complicated to install a separate natural gas meter to the basement).

So, I'm thinking, when I install the gas wall furnace, I can put a meter in its gas inlet and that way I can charge the renter according to the amount of gas they end up using. This would be a win for sustainability because it would encourage the renter to be responsible with gas usage, and would also be a win for me because I won't worry about the renter being irresponsible with gas usage on my dime. **My question: has anyone tried metering gas usage in a part of their home?** I searched for "gas furnace meter" and came up with [this search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=gas%20furnace%20meter), would any of these work?

Comment: To really submeter, you install a meter and read it (directly or remotely) and bill based on it. But there are potential legal issues involved - it can vary quite a bit by jurisdiction. Essentially you become "the gas utility" for your tenant and that can raise a lot of issues. The alternative is an estimate based on degree-days, floor space and BTUs.

Comment: They sell gas meters: https://www.ekmmetering.com/products/3-4-pulse-output-gas-meter for example. You should remove "furnace" from your search, and you'll find them. But it's illegal to sub-meter is some places, you'll need to check local law.

Comment: Having a separate gas service put in for the apartment *may* be the only legal option.

Comment: if your goal is to save the tenant money by letting them heat more efficiently, and you're willing to spend a few grand making it happen (wall furnace ~$1000 + meter ??? + install) then the right answer is an extended range heat pump. All electric.  Keep the existing electric strip heating as emergency heat for those few subzero days the heat pump cannot run.   This also provides A/C, hopefully your tenant won't mind too much lol.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thanks. It's an intriguing technology that I've not heard of before for some reason. I need to look into it (so I can understand how this thing can extract heat from 10F cold air outside and deliver this heat inside). I always thought those outdoor fan-vent things were for central airconditioners.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica wrote is an awesome idea for you! Look into mini-split systems, almost all of them can run in reverse, and provide both A/C and heat. Some mini-split systems can even be installed DIY (Mr. Cool advertises this all the time.)

Comment: "it **may** be too expensive/complicated to install a separate ... meter" (emphasis added). Instead of speculating, why don't you give your local gas company a call and actually ask them what it would take to install a separate meter. You're likely right, but it may not be as bad as you're thinking.

Comment: @FreeMan point noted, and it's been added to my to do list. Thanks.